# Upload PHP: File size issues

Tags: php, upload

I am testing upload on my website with PHP on Apache2, but i got some issues:
I can upload 40k file but not over 100K the move_uploaded_file send me false.
Although I set my php.ini to accept 500Mo file for the test.
Also i put this at the end of the script:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '500M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '500M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 4000);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 4000);
```

Also here is my code :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '500M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '500M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 4000);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 4000);

$dossier = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/';
$fichier = basename($_FILES['avatar']['name']);
$taille_maxi = 100000000;
$taille = filesize($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);
$extensions = array('.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg');
$extension = strrchr($_FILES['avatar']['name'], '.'); 

if(!in_array($extension, $extensions))
{
     $erreur = 'WRONG EXTENSION';
}
if($taille>$taille_maxi)
{
     $erreur = 'TOO HEAVY';
}


if(!isset($erreur))
{
     $fichier = strtr($fichier, 
          'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ', 
          'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');
     $fichier = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '-', $fichier);
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $dossier . $fichier))
     {
          echo 'Upload OK !';
     }
     else
     {
          echo 'Upload Error';

     }
}
else
{
     echo $erreur;
}
?>
```

I always get the answer 'Upload Error' without any PHP error:

```
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $dossier . $fichier))
     {
          echo 'Upload OK !';
     }
     else
     {
          echo 'Upload Error';

     }
```

Thanks in advance for help !
Have a nice day.

Comment: You should make PHP warnings and errors visible for better troubleshooting. Put `display_errors=On` in your php.ini and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in your script.

Comment: Try set upload limit in php.ini file, and restart your apache server.

Comment: `display_errors` was `On`, i add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and suddendly the script works. I have no clue why, i didn't restarted apache or something like that.
Thanks very much ! Have a nice day

Comment: To 蒋艾伦, 
The max input and max upload where set to 500M in the php.ini but thanks for help anyway !

Comment: The "RESTART" magic strikes again. :)

Comment: i didn't "RESTART" anything, this is REAL magic !! Have a nice day

Comment: Oops, I missed the "didnt".